# Problem with global event_scheduler on mySql

Tags: mysql, events, scheduler

```
delimiter | 
create event check 
on schedule every 1 day starts (select time('15:00:00')) 
do begin 
call check_1(); 
call check_2();  
call check_3(); 
end | 
delimiter ;
```

The problem is that the code works, but works only if MySQL is opened at that time. I have already set up

> set global event_scheduler=on

And I wrote

> event_scheduler=on

under [mysqld] in my.ini.
But it still not work, if mysql (or the pc) is closed, the scheduler doesn't work... can someone help my? Thanks before.

Comment: 'if mysql (or the pc) is closed' - not surprised server has to be running. (nb check is a reserved word)

Comment: I know the name is not 'check'

Comment: Anyway, there's no way to let the scheduler works if the pc is sw

Comment: if the pc is sw ? - translation please

Comment: do a SHOW PROCESSLIST
 and see if there is a event scheduled

Comment: @P.Salmon if the pc is closed*

Comment: @nbk yes, and It's work but only if my pc is open. I wondering if there is a way to make it works when the pc is closed too

Comment: the service must be running to call an event, but what you want is the Task Scheduler, that will run your scrits and then shut it again down.

Comment: What is Task Scheduler? I'm sorry but I'm a student and we studied only the event scheduler...